# Is it appropriate to use POST request instead of GET request when fetching data based on filtering object in nodej.js/express

Tags: node.js, express, rest, post, get

Is it appropriate to use POST request in node.js/express when trying to FETCH data from mysql database based on a filtering object that might look something like this:

```
filter = {
createdBefore:"2022-12-10",
maximumSize:"10",
minimumSize:"2",
contains:[{productId:"1", quantity:"100"}, {productId:"2", quantity:"200"}, {productId:"3", quantity:"300"}]
}
```

Now this is just a dummy data, it does not serve an actual purpose - i provided it to help visualise what i mean by "filtering object". So, in this scenario is it okai to use POST method and pass it inside body or should i still use GET method with query params.

Answer (score 0):

From **W3C** docs:

> Use GET if:
> The interaction is more like a question (i.e., it is a safe operation such as a query, read operation, or lookup).
> Use POST if:
> The interaction is more like an order, or
> The interaction changes the state of the resource in a way that the user would perceive (e.g., a subscription to a service), or
> The user be held accountable for the results of the interaction.

The whole document is "**URIs, Addressability, and the use of HTTP GET and POST**", and can be reached [here](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html)

P.S As a side note, GET requests can have their body